# Grub wont install during ubuntu server 9.10 x64 install

Tags: raid, ubuntu

Ive brought the parts for a new server, setup a raid1 for the OS and begun to install ubuntu server 9.10 x64.

it sailed through partioning the HDD no problem. but now it wont isntall grub, just brings up the installer menu and every time i press install grub it starts saying "installing 'grub2'" but then brings the menu back up.

i tried lilo but that errors.

my install disk passes integrity checks

anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 1):

You can try manually installing grub.

Bring up a second console (ALT+F2). You should have a /target directory which is your installed system. What you want to do is chroot to that directory and run grub-install.

To do this execute the following commands:

```
chroot /target /bin/bash
grub-install /dev/sda
```

In the above example I have assumed you've installed Ubuntu onto the first drive.
If that works you also want to install grub onto any of the other drives that host your /boot RAID-1 partition, e.g. /dev/sdb

Even if this doesn't work you should see some relatively useful error messages which you can use to better troubleshoot the problem (Google is your friend).

If everything installs without issue you should be able to restart the computer and have it boot into Ubuntu.